# How to use JSON file using clientbundle in gwt

Tags: java, json, gwt

I have a static JSON file and I want to access it in my GWT code. The *custom-report.json* file is in the *client* package of the project. I am adding it in ClientBundle and trying to access it but I get an error

```
public interface AppBundle extends ClientBundle {

    @Source("custom-report.json")
    public TextResource jsonData();
    public static final AppBundle INSTANCE = GWT.create(AppBundle.class);

}
```

To use it in my code, this is what I am doing:

```
AppBundle.INSTANCE.mystyle().ensureInjected();

JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(AppBundle.INSTANCE.jsonData().getText()));
```

This gives me compilation error

```
[ERROR] Line 29: No source code is available for type org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to use the JSON file in GWT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONParser` that is provided by `GWT` instead of the  `org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser`.

```
JSONValue value = JSONParser.parse(json);
JSONObject productsObj = value.isObject();
JSONArray productsArray = productsObj.get("products").isArray();
```

Comment: The issue is with accessing the JSON file. I am not sure if this is the correct way to access the file. Because the error is because my code is not able to read the file. It gives error at the following line:                                                                                        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(AppBundle.INSTANCE.jsonData().getText()));

Comment: you can't use a `FileReader` on the client side. You should use `ClientBundle` and the `gwt.json` package